# When I select Edit it should display the value which is stored in my database In Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have Privilege list

```
<table width="60%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">

        <tr align="center" valign="middle">
        <td width="35" height="35"><strong>ID</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Roles</strong> </td>
        <td><strong>Action</strong></td>
        </tr>

        <tr align="center" valign="middle" ng-repeat="x in privilegename">
        <td width="35" height="35" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">{{$index+1}}</td>
        <td align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-left: 10px;">{{x.privilege_name}}</td>          
        <td width="250" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <span style="padding-left:5px;">          
        <a class="common-link" href="" ng-click="edit(x)"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
        <a class="common-link" href="" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </span>
        </td>
        </tr>          
        </table>
```

And the form to manage privilege it should also act as Edit form. It have one dropdown which consists of privilege name and next one is checklist consists of menus. When user select the edit option in list it should display the value which is stored in database.

Here is my controller for edit function

```
 $scope.edit = function(x)
       {
        $scope.privilege = x;
        console.log($scope.privilege);
        $scope.submit = "Update";

        $scope.url = "/updateprivilege";
       }
```

My checklist in Form :

```
<tr>
                    <td  height="40" align="left" valign="middle"><span class="head-three">
                    Menus</span></td>
                    <td width="20" align="left" valign="middle">:</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="menu in menulist" class="menu_checklist">
                    <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    name="privilege_menu"
                    value="{{menu}}"
                    ng-model="privilege.privilege_menu"
                    selected
                    ng-click="toggleSelection(menu)"> {{menu}}
            </td>



            </tr>
```

For dropdown its working fine. But Checklist is empty.

Comment: what you are getting in `$scope.privilege` can you show ?..

Comment: full details of the privilege - _id,privilege selected menu [].  Now I have used  ng-checked="selectedMenu.indexOf(menu) > -1" and its showing the selected menu for selected employee. now the problem is ng-click when i try to edit its check all the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ng-checked in checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="privilege_menu" value="{{menu}}" 
ng-model="privilege.privilege_menu" ng-checked={{isSelected(menu) > -1}} 
ng-click="toggleSelection(menu)">{{menu}}
```

controller

```
$scope.selectedACArr = [];
$scope.isSelected = function(menuObj) {
    return $scope.selectedACArr.map(function(e) {
    return e._id;
    }).indexOf(menuObj._id);
};
```

Comment: Thank you ..its working good but when i try to edit it checked all the value

Comment: Issue Fixed I have used ng-model and ng-checked . Actually ng-checked should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior. and thank you so much...